# sending email to IP address via postfix

Tags: ubuntu, networking, email, postfix

My friend and I have configured two Postfix mail servers on our laptops. We succeeded in sending mail to a real network (to some Gmail accounts) from our computers; that was the easy part.

We now want to send an email from one laptop to the other; both laptops are on the same network (they're using the same WIFI) and they both have Postfix installed on them (OSes of laptops are Ubuntu).

We tried to send email like this:

```
rcpt to: postmaster@[IP Address]
```

Yet, we have the same IP (when we check on sites like [this](http://www.whatismyip.com/)), since we are on same network. We aren't network veterans, either.

Here is the question: is it possible to send email from one laptop to the other, on the same network? If it is so, how could it be done?

Moreover:

- my computer's local IP: 192.168.174.128
- friends local IP: 192.168.200.128

When I try to send an email via Postfix this command does it right:

```
rcpt to: username@[192.168.174.128]
```

But, it isn't working when I try to send email to my friend's Postfix:

```
rcpt to: username@[192.168.200.128]
```

He can't receive the mail that I've sent.

Comment: Why you are not using `/etc/hosts` file ?

Comment: Is there any online resource you recommend me to read about /etc/hosts file, sir? I am kind of a passionate newbie about networking and linux systems.

Comment: Please check my ans and let me know, if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can setup your Internet DNS Server with [BIND](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto)
2. OR You can Specify, your IP with hostname in `/etc/hosts` file

Example: I'm assuming that you have hosted laptop1.local, laptop2.local as virtual domain:

```
192.168.174.128 laptop1.local
192.168.200.128 laptop2.local
```

One more thing, whenever you are sending mail just watch the mail log using:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

If you want to force Postfix to refer to `/etc/hosts`, then set the following parameters in `main.cf`:

```
lmtp_host_lookup = native
smtp_host_lookup=native
#disable_dns_lookups = yes
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
```

Also, don't forget to reload Postfix after making changes in `main.cf`.

Comment: I edited hosts file. Should I send email to username@laptop2.local right now?
`rcpt to: username@laptop2.local`

Comment: Yes, you are right..

Comment: @EkremDoğan - Rahul is correct, look in your mail.log file, you should see connection attempts being made by your server to deliver the mail to your friends mail server. You should see messages that the message was sent successfully if it's working correctly.

Comment: I am assuming that, you have hosted laptop1.local,laptop2.local as virtual domain

Comment: I tried all you said above, I am afraid I do something wrong. Here is the related part of mail.log file:

`Jul 10 00:35:32 ubuntu postfix/smtp[13168]: 18DCD633D6: to=<ozturk@laptop2.local> relay=none, delay=26, delays=25/0.05/0.19/0, dsn5.4.4, status=bounced (unable to look up host laptop2.local: Name or service not known)`

a bit down:

`sender non-delivery notification`

Comment: @RahulPatil there is no hosting. Just two laptops connecting to same wifi using ubuntu as OS and postfix installed on them.

Comment: @EkremDoğan please do the changes in main.cf as I mentioned in ans

Comment: @RahulPatil - yup no problem.

Comment: @RahulPatil and @ slm thanks you guys so much. I figured main problem out, it was a rookie mistake. I was trying to run ubuntu on vmware and I didn't realize it could make any problem. I installed ubuntu on our harddisks. Edited the main.cf as you said. Now, We succesfully send and received emails.

Comment: thanks for you update, it's important to us. I also wish to inform you that, with current setting, you wont be able to send outside (Other than `/etc/hosts`), since we have set `native` option only, we can make it `native, dns` if you want to send outside also. I'm not 100% sure but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `[192.168.200.128]` to $mydestination in postfix comfiguration?

It seems to work according to some reports
https://www.zimbra.com/forums/administrators/21994-solved-correct-zmlocalconfig-e-syntax-new-postfix-parameter.html

Comment: I did right after you said, but it didnt work in my case