# sendmail through virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, email, virtual-machine, sendmail

I am successfully performing some very basic SMTP sending in my machine with a basic Python script:

```
.... things ...

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, recievers, message.format(now, now))
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

It works fine both in my machine and in a Ubuntu server I have in Virtual Box. Now I would like to send one email from one server using the other server as a host.

I tried in my virtual host to change

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
```

with

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('IP of my PC') #IP get from "ifconfig -a"
```

but does not work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: refer this page http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82454/sending-email-to-ip-address-via-postfix/82456#82456

Comment: I get the same message both adding the IP or through IP in `/etc/hosts` as you suggest in your answer, @RahulPatil. Always `socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Comment: Connection refused, means on remote machine port 25 is not running/open

Comment: also you can check `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: @RahulPatil If I do `nmap localhost -p25` I get the message `25/tcp open  smtp`. Is it right? Otherwise, how can I solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: yes, when you are sending to other machine , there also port 25 open as in your machine

Comment: But @RahulPatil, does the output I showed mean that my port 25 is opened?

Comment: yes, but on your localhost , not remote host

Comment: OK, now I see with `nmap ip.ip.ip.ip -p25`. So how can I open it? Also feel free to post this as an answer so I can thank you by accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: may be postfix/mailserver only listen only on local interface (127.0.0.1), you need to run mailserver all interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works fine both in my machine and in a Ubuntu server I have in
>   Virtual Box. Now I would like to send one email from one server using
>   the other server as a host.

As you mentioned it's working in both machine with `localhost` not with `IP address of host` then, might be mail server is running only on localhost, So you need to Bind Postfix Mail Server To all or specific IP Address to interfaces.

**Postfix IP address bind configuration:**

Open `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file

Append / modify line as follows to bind to localhost (127.0.0.1) only:

```
inet_interfaces = NEW_IP_ADDRESS,127.0.0.1
```

Save and close the file. You need to stop and start Postfix when this parameter changes. So type the following to restart Postfix:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

---

**If you are using sendmail:**

Open `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Find the line starting with DaemonPortOptions and then replace `Addr=127.0.0.1` to `Addr=0.0.0.0`

Note: 0.0.0.0 means all active interfaces.

then restart sendmail and Verify that everything is working fine:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 25
tail -f /var/log/maillog
```