# Email from Host1 to Host2 on LAN

Tags: email, postfix

This may be a simple question but if I have HOST1 (no postfix/MTA) where I launch in terminal `mail -s "test email" user@HOST2 < /dev/null` so that I can send email to HOST2 (has postfix as MTA), why do I get the following error:

```
mail: Null message body; hope that's ok
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

By doing `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` I get the following:

```
Dec  1 17:00:24 HOST1 postfix/sendmail[21790]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
```

This is suggesting I need Postfix installed on HOST1 too? That seems a bit overkill ...
Note that HOST2 is accepting telnet on port 25:

```
user@HOST1:~$ telnet HOST2 smtp
Trying 192.168.2.5...
Connected to HOST2.domain.home.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 HOST2.domain.home ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
```

I know I'm missing something really simple here so bear with me. My question is do I need an MTA on HOST1 too?

These are the relevant bits in my `main.cf` on HOST2:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = HOST2.domain.home
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = HOST2.domain.home, HOST2, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 192.168.2.0/24 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 192.168.2.5, 127.0.0.1 
inet_protocols = ipv4
myorigin = /etc/mailname
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
```

Please note that both HOST1 and HOST2 are on the same subnet 192.168.2.0/24. I have `/etc/hosts` configured on both machines with the respective LAN IPs. No that my objective is to install an MTA on my LAN to simple get other machines to crontab emails with system stats, etc. to the centralised MTA and then I use Thunderbird to connect to the MTA machine an download all the LAN system emails. If the MTA is responding to port 25 when I telnet to it from HOST1, then why can't I use the `mail` command to send an email? If I have to install an MTA on every machine, that is a lot of work ... although [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82454/sending-email-to-ip-address-via-postfix) implies that I may have to actually do just that.

Comment: You need _something_ to get the messages off host1 and onto host2. Postfix is one option. msmtp is another.

Comment: So it seems that I need an MTA on HOST1 if I want to use the `mail` command. In fact, when I use Thunderbird on HOST1 and get it to use port 25 for smtp on HOST2, bingo! It works.

Answer (score 1):

mailx (AKA mail) can send directly using the smtp option

```
mail -s "test email" -S smtp=HOST2 user@HOST2 < /dev/null
```

This tells it not to use an MTA, by defalt sendmail.

Comment: Are you sure? I get `unrecognised option -S` ... in fact, `man mail` has no reference to `-S` option nor to the possibility of being able to define the SMTP server.

Comment: There are different variants of `mail` command. The two most common are the simple Berkeley mail (the "original" `mail` command), and the more advanced `mailx` which is commonly installed on Linux as `mail`. `mailx`  does recognize the `-S` parameter, and Berkeley mail does not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. You cannot use `mail` command from HOST1 to HOST2 without having an MTA installed on HOST1. It works if you use Thunderbird on HOST1, which meets my objective of demonstrating that the MTA on HOST2 is accepting emails from the LAN on port 25